# ms access compare value with average of trailing seven days

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data set which contains people, dates, food, and quantity of food. I want a query where I specify a person and a date and have two values returned: the quantity of food eaten on the date chosen and the average quantity of food eaten over the previous 7 days.

So if I pick Abe on 1/10/2013 I get "1" and "3.6" because he ate 1 piece of fruit on 1/10 and an average of 3.6 pieces of fruit each day between 1/3 and 1/9.

name,thedate,qty,food

```
name,thedate,qty,food
abe,1/2/2013,1,orange
abe,1/2/2013,3,pear
abe,1/3/2013,3,orange
abe,1/4/2013,2,orange
abe,1/4/2013,2,plum
abe,1/5/2013,1,orange
abe,1/7/2013,7,onion
abe,1/8/2013,2,orange
abe,1/9/2013,3,orange
abe,1/9/2013,2,pear
abe,1/10/2013,1,orange
jen,1/1/2013,2,orange
jen,1/4/2013,3,orange
jen,1/5/2013,2,orange
```

Comment: It looks like abe ate an average of 2.75 pieces of fruit in those 7 days

Comment: Between 1/3 and 1/9 I get 3+4+1+7+2+5=22 and then 22/6=3.6

Comment: ah I see, you are not counting `1/6/2013` as a day because you have no data for that day (not what I was expecting) and you're counting the orange and the plum on `1/4` as the total for that day (which makes sense)

Comment: See my updated answer. More like that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a correlated subquery to find this

```
Select 
  Parent.name
  , Parent.thedate
  , Parent.qty, 
(SELECT avg(qty)
  FROM yourTable
  where name = parent.name  
     and thedate < parent.theDate 
     and theDate>=dateadd("d", datediff("d",0, parent.theDate)-7,0) 
  group by name) as previousSeven
from yourTable Parent
```

If this is actually on a per fruit-type basis you can join on that too with `and fruit = parent.fruit` you need to add fruit to the `group by`, too

**Update**

To find, not an average, but the sum of the number of fruit divided by the number of distinct days with data in the last 7 days you will need something more like this (it get's a lot more complicated because access doesn't support the `Select count(distinct something)` syntax)

```
Select
Name
, theDate
, qty
, sumOfPreviousSeven/distinctDaysWithDataLastSeven
from (
    Select 
      Parent.name
      , Parent.thedate
      , Parent.qty
    , (SELECT sum(qty)
      FROM table4
      where name = parent.name  
         and thedate < parent.theDate 
         and theDate>=dateadd("d", datediff("d",0, parent.theDate)-7,0) 
      group by name) as sumOfPreviousSeven

    , (select top 1 count(distinctDates) from 
            (select dateadd("d", datediff("d",0, theDate),0) as distinctDates, name  from table4
        group by dateadd("d", datediff("d",0, theDate),0), name)
        where name = parent.name 
            and  distinctDates < parent.theDate 
            and distinctDates>=dateadd("d", datediff("d",0, parent.theDate)-7,0) 
        group by name) as distinctDaysWithDataLastSeven
from table4 Parent) as base
```

Comment: My date field is actually date/time so when I run your query I do not get counts per day, but per date/time. I should know this, but what do I add to your query to fix this? For example, in my sample data I show just the date as 1/2 but the actual data is 1/2/2013 5:51:00 AM and 1/2/2013 12:00:00 PM. Thanks!